# Convert schematic from Eagle 6 to Eagle 5

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

Is there a way to convert a .sch file in Eagle 6 to Eagle 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Generally speaking, conversions from later versions of software to previous versions are not feasible, especially with CAD programs, because of the additional features that are added. In theory, it would be possible, but it would be extremely difficult, and very few users would require it.

Why do you need it?

Comment: the schematic was done in 6.  Then to lay it out going to be bigger than the min pcb size.  The issue is we only have a license for 5 though.  Non ideal situation and I'm trying to see if there is a way out.

Comment: Redo the schematic in V5, it shouldn't take long. Or, upgrade your V5 license to V6.

Comment: Altium Designer, at least, is fully forward and backwards compatable, between version 6 through version 11 (the most recent). If you import a file from a newer version, and it has newer features, it will explicitly tell you exactly what it had to remove from the new file to make it compatible. (The new features are mostly fancy stuff, like varying pad sizes across the layer stack). I have multiple computers with multiple versions of altium on them, and I can work on any of them. It's one of the things I really like about altium.

Answer (score 3):

You could write an ULP that lists parts with locations and nets.  You could include more info like classes, etc.  This would be run on V6 and save the output to a file.

Then you would need to write another script to be run on V5 that reads this file and recreates your schematic sheet by sheet, part by part, and net by net.

Answer (score 2):

No, although it would be pointless anyway.  Nobody with more than a couple neurons rattling around their skull is running Eagle 6.  That was a major change from version 5, with a completely new file format.  It will be a year or two at least before version 6 is ready for real work.  Let the clueless continue to find the bugs in version 6 for the rest of us and give Cadsoft the time it takes to fix them.  Check back by mid 2013 at the earliest and see how things are going.  In the mean time stick to version 5, which is quite solid.

Comment: A lot of negativity with not a lot of real evidences.

Comment: @CMP: Wrong, there is a great deal of evidence out there.  Take a look at the Eagle forums thru element14 or at Eagle Central (http://www.eaglecentral.ca/forums) and you'll see just about every post is about a version 6 issue and that there are a lot of bugs.  Eagle 6 clearly isn't ready for real work.  Look at the forums and see for youself.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Other then the first word, your answer is nothing more then a comment. I could very well see the OP having all of the issues you are talking about so they are wanting to convert back to version 5 and is trying to figure out how to convert all of their files back with them.

Comment: @Kellenjb: It is a simple question for which the answer is "no".  There isn't much more to say to answer the question, so I gave some additional background and recommendation.

Comment: @OlinLathrop If there wasn't much more to say, then Leon's answer should have been plenty, especially since he actually explaining the reasoning behind the no.

Comment: @Kellenjb: Just like Leon gave additional information, I gave different additional information.  The fact that it was a major change with a different file formats, that it is currently very buggy, and that it will stay that way for some time I think are reasonable additional points.  Anyone that doesn't believe the version 6 problems needs to check the Eagle forums.